# Fitting linear combination of lists

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have the following expectation equation, which expects a strain over multiple temperature

```
E(Y) = c + Sum ai*ti  i=1 to n
```

I define it as

```
def residuals(params, xData, yData ):
    expecation = params[-1] + np.zeros(1)
    for j in range (2):
        for i in range(len(xData)):
            expecation += params[i]*xData[j][i]
    diff = expecation - yData
    return diff
```

I use the following leastsquare

```
  combinedList = [t1List, t2List]
    fit, ier = leastsq(residuals, [1,1,0], args=( combinedList, strainList), maxfev=5000)
```

I would like to know how to use the coffecients to get the expected strain and plot it.

Comment: Are you using `scipy.optimize.leastsq`?

Comment: yes I'm using it